# Python not returning all values to system but replacing it with ...

Tags: python, windows-7, numpy, scipy, system

I have a piece of python code which returns values to the system after the input arguments have been defined. I am having problems with the number of samples that have been returned to the system.

I have the following bit of code:

```
import sys
import numpy.random

def Weibull_Random(alpha,beta,Iterations):

    a=alpha
    b=beta


    weibull_rand=numpy.random.weibull(a,[Iterations])

    rand_sample=((weibull_rand)*b)

    return (rand_sample)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alpha = float(sys.argv[1])
    beta = float(sys.argv[2])
    Iterations = float(sys.argv[3])
    sys.stdout.write(str(Weibull_Random(alpha,beta,Iterations)))
```

The number of samples is defined by `Iterations`, we can set alpha and beta to a range of different numbers lets say `alpha=2` and `beta=15` for this problem.
If Iterations=1000 or less all the numbers are returned to the system. If Iterations=1001 or greater then the system returns

```
[ 15.33018892  3.22693971  10.02243413 ...,  8.87121152  14.29458731
  15.13458017]
```

Does anyone know how to return all the values to the system?

I'm using windows 7 and Python 3 with Numpy and Scipy (pyzo2013b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to the system, but caused by the formatting employed by `numpy`.  The easiest fix is to modify your script to invoke `numpy.set_printoptions` like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    alpha = float(sys.argv[1])
    beta = float(sys.argv[2])
    Iterations = float(sys.argv[3])
    numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=Iterations)   # Force threshold to iteration count.
    sys.stdout.write(str(Weibull_Random(alpha,beta,Iterations)))
```

In this snippet, I force `numpy` to set the summarization threshold to the number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last line as follow, and you will see all values:

```
sys.stdout.write(str(Weibull_Random(alpha,beta,Iterations).tolist()))
```

Comment: Thanks Falsetru this also did the trick and it was quicker but it wouldn't allow me to interpret the data how I wanted to at the other end with Matlab, so I used Brett's way.